Check if dates are within two days of each other
I have two string variables that are dates in format YYYY-MM-DD. I am trying to check if my "finish" variable is within 2 days of my "start" variable. What is the most efficient way of doing this?
I have done some research online and see a lot of something similar to below, but I am not sure if I am on the right track at all.
var start = '2024-06-11'
var finish = '2024-06-13'

var startDate = new Date(start)
var finishDate = new Date(finish)

var plusTwoDays = startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 3)


plusTwoDays and + 3 don't seem to agree with each other.

Just subtract startDate from the finishDate, then test if the results is less than or equal to the number of milliseconds in 1 day.

if you can afford another library in the project I'd go with Luxon math for code readability
  import luxon from 'luxon';

  const dt = luxon.DateTime.local();
  const threeDaysLater = dt.plus({ days: 3 });  

Date is a weird object :)
so you can do Unix timestamp math for sure, but this isn't quire readable and convenient
  const threeDays = 60 * 60 * 24 * 3 * 1000; // seconds times hours times days times milliseconds
  const afterThreeDays = Date.now() + threeDays;

